# How to do Verilog variable part select with % on both sides of colon?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I understand that for variable part select, there can't be a variable on both sides of the colon:

```
a_vect[ 8*i +: 8] // == a_vect[(8*i+7) : 8*i]
```

However, I need to convert this code:

```
a_vect[(i*16+3)%64 : (i*16)%64]
```

How do I deal with the "%64" on both sides of the colon?

Answer (score 2):

The +3 won't cause the mod to wrap, so just remove it:

```
a_vect[(i*16)%64 +: 4]
```

(If it did, the original code wouldn't work anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use shift operation:

```
temp = (a_vect >> ((i*16)%64));
```

If temp variable is not defined as 4-bit, use:

```
temp = (a_vect >> ((i*16)%64)) & 4'hF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_vect[(i*16+3)%64 : (i*16)%64]
```

when elaborated

```
i=0 ==> a_vect[3:0]
i=1 ==> a_vect[19:16]
i=2 ==> a_vect[35:32]
i=3 ==> a_vect[51:48]
i=4 ==> a_vect[3:0]
```

u can use this type

```
  for(genvar i=0;i<64;i+16)
        a_vect[i+:4]
```